# What is the line between salesmanship and dishonesty on a resume?

Tags: resume

A friend of mine and I are writing our resumes for applying for summer internships after our first year. We don’t have a lot to put on them that consists of actual accomplishments.

My friends view is that we can say anything that is factually true. In our cases, our schooling is paid for as a perk of our parents employment.

He thinks we should put it as that we have a £12,000 full fee scholarship. His father agrees. Can we get away with this? We didn’t technically even apply for the scholarship ourselves.

Comment: What does the company actually call it?

Comment: You get free schooling, others **earned** their scholarship...

Comment: If you ever have to ask a question along the lines of "Can we get away with this", then you're considering a lie or a criminal act of some sort. Don't do it.

Comment: *We didn’t technically even apply for the scholarship ourselves.* - Does this mean that all company employee's kids get their tuition paid for automatically or does it just mean that your parents had to do the work of submitting your grades or something?

Comment: Scholarships are useless information unless you did something to earn them. For instance, my family was low income enough that I qualified for a Pell Grant from the US government. But does that show anything to my potential employer about my abilities. No it doesn't. Therefore don't include it.

Answer (score 4):

You can put anything that is factually true, no one really cares much at that level.

But you don't have a scholarship, so that is not factually true.

Answer (score 2):

One fact for resumes is that you might be asked to explain any line on there. If you're wondering whether or not to put a specific line on a resume, think of how you would answer in an interview if asked about it or performed a background check, and whether or not them discovering the truth would damage your credibility.

In your specific case, if you list that you're receiving a large scholarship, and the interviewer is curious about how you got it, they're going to likely find out that you did nothing to earn it and be specifically unimpressed. Personally, I would not list it.

In terms of creating a resume with little to no experience, you have to be creative:

- Write about skills you've learned in your studies so far.
- Talk about jobs and or volunteering experience that are unrelated to the jobs you're applying to.
- Highlight other skills or accomplishments to demonstrate your character.

If you're applying for entry-level internships, just remember that the company is looking for someone who doesn't have a lot of experience.

Comment: Think both about what you would say if asked about a point, and about how finding out the details would affect a reader's opinion of your honesty.

Comment: *think of how you would answer in an interview if asked about it.* Also, think about how it will look when the employer does a background check! Listing that you earned a full scholarship, and then having a background check reveal that you got tuition assistance because of your parent's jobs, might be a fire-able offense to some people.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan thanks for the input. I edited the answer slightly.

Comment: @dwizum thanks for the input. I edited the answer slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Your tuition is paid for as a benefit/perk of your parents employment. Either say that or don't say anything. There's no benefit or advantage to lying about it. You've nothing to gain and everything to lose. Why would it even matter how it's paid for?